# SQLite syntax error at UPDATE - works in SQLiteStudio, not in my code

Tags: sqlite, syntax, sqlitestudio

my problem is, that I wrote an update, checked it in SQLiteStudio, it works fine.
When I execute the same in my program, it throws a syntax error.
('near "FROM": syntax error')

There is a difference in the *sqlite3.dll*s, because SQLiteStudio uses a 64bit one, my code is a 32bit Windows application, so it uses a 32bit dll. I found already some little differences (e.g. parenthesis is accepted or not) earlier in the function of the two versions, but there was always a solution to avoid the problem.
(Unfortunately I don't know any exact version number, but the 32bit version is digitally signed by Idera Inc. in 20. February 2021., it is included by Delphi 10.4 Community version.)

But this time I have no idea, what can be the problem.

The original form of my UPDATE is:

```
UPDATE wRoutes SET tfFeedPt = fitt.tid FROM
(SELECT wr.id AS wid, tf.id AS tid FROM wRoutes wr 
JOIN xyposFitt tf 
ON wr.posX = tf.posX AND wr.posY = tf.posY
   AND wr.drNum = tf.drNum AND wr.page = tf.page
WHERE endpoint = "X") AS fitt
WHERE wRoutes.id = fitt.wid
```

It's perferct in SQLiteStudio, but throws the mentioned exception from my code.

I searched in Google a lot, and found a tip which seemed to be promising -
to use the WITH  UPDATE form, so I tried this version too:

```
WITH fitt AS
(SELECT wr.id AS wid, tf.id AS tid FROM wRoutes wr
JOIN xyposFitt tf  
ON wr.posX = tf.posX AND wr.posY = tf.posY  
AND wr.drNum = tf.drNum AND wr.page = tf.page 
 WHERE endpoint = "X")
UPDATE wRoutes SET tfFeedPt = fitt.tid 
FROM fitt
WHERE wRoutes.id = fitt.wid
```

It worked again in SQLiteStudio, but not in my code.
I tried the table name aliases with and without using "AS".
E.g. "FROM wRoutes wr" and "FROM wRoutes AS wr".
The result is the same: SQLiteStudio OK, my code: 'near "FROM": syntax error'.

Could somebody tell, what is wrong with my UPDATE command?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For the UPDATE...FROM syntax you need SQLite 3.33.0+. Check your version.

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution. 
I queried the version of the original dll from the code. It was 3.8.10.2.
SQLiteStudio uses 3.35.4.
I replaced the dll under Delphi with the latest, downloaded from the SQLite website (it is 3.37.2), and now it works. 

I didn't upgrade it until now, because there was a problem, which didn't happen when I executed my program from the IDE, but it appeared when I ran it on another machine, where the latest dll was deployed (as far as I remember, it was the parenthesis problem), so the original "Delphi version" seemed to be better. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Forpas' comment contains the correct answer:
the UPDATE...FROM syntax needs SQLite version 3.33.0+.
Upgrade of the dll to the latest (3.37.2) solved the problem.